# Replace given occurance of text in Ms Word document using C sharp

Tags: c#, text, ms-word, replace

I m coding in c sharp and I need to find how to replace given occurrence of a text in a 
MS-Word Document using c sharp.

I found so many examples on the web regarding replacing the first occurrence and replacing all occurrences but none on a given occurrence.

An example of what I want is as follows:

> hello world hello test testing hello
>   .. hello ... test hello

to be

> hello world hello test testing hello
>   .. tree ... test hello

That is the 4th occurance of 'hello' to be replaced with 'tree'.

Looking forward for a solution...

Thanks

Comment: You mean you want to write code that executes in a Word document (like a macro), or do you want to execute code on a server that modifies a Word document?

Comment: Actually I want in the way in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/Application_to_Word.aspx. This link provides how to replace one and replace all. So I want in that way and that is what I require

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
static string ReplaceOccurrence(string input, string wordToReplace, string replaceWith, int occToReplace)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, string.Format("([\\w]*)", wordToReplace), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            int occurrencesFound = 0;
            int captureIndex = 0;

            foreach (Match matchItem in matches)
            {
                if (matchItem.Value == wordToReplace)
                {
                    occurrencesFound++;
                    if (occurrencesFound == occToReplace)
                    {
                        captureIndex = matchItem.Index;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (captureIndex > 0)
            {
                return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", input.Substring(0, captureIndex), replaceWith, input.Substring(captureIndex + wordToReplace.Length));
            } else 
            {
                return input;
            }
        }
```

You will have to put a `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top.

Comment: You would use this like this...
`string output = ReplaceOccurrence(input, "hello","test",4);` where input is the string to be searched.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
        string s = "hello world hello test testing hello .. hello ... test hello";
        string[] value = { "hello" };
        string[] strList = s.Split(value,255,StringSplitOptions.None);
        string newStr = "";
        int replacePos = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < strList.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i != replacePos - 1) && (strList.Length != i + 1))
            {
                newStr += strList[i] + value[0];
            }
            else if (strList.Length != i + 1)
            {
                newStr += strList[i] + "tree";
            }
        }
```